# this.props.t not being picked up by i18next-scanner in react native project with Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

I am working on a react native app build with Typescript, and I'm using `react-i18next` and `i18next` for translation. This is my `i18next-scanner` config:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var typescript = require("typescript");

function typescriptTransform(options) {
    options = options || {};
    if (!options.extensions) {
        options.extensions = [".tsx"];
    }

    return function transform(file, enc, done) {
        const extension = path.extname(file.path);
        const parser = this.parser;
        let content = fs.readFileSync(file.path, enc);

        if (options.extensions.indexOf(extension) !== -1) {
            content = typescript.transpileModule(content, {
            compilerOptions: {
                target: 'es2018'
            },
            fileName: path.basename(file.path)
            }).outputText;
        parser.parseTransFromString(content);
        parser.parseFuncFromString(content);
    }
        done();
    };
};

module.exports = {
    options: {
        defaultLng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        func: {
            list: ['t', 'i18next.t', 'i18n.t'],
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
        },
        trans: {
            component: 'Trans',
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        },
        transform: typescriptTransform({ extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'] }),
        lngs: ['en', 'nl'],
        ns: ['account', 'common'],
        defaultNs: 'common',
        resource: {
            loadPath: 'app/{{ns}}/i18n/{{lng}}.json',
            savePath: 'app/{{ns}}/i18n/{{lng}}.json',
        },
    }
};
```

The problem is that the scanner doesn't pick up the use of `this.props.t`. It works if I use `i18n.t` and `i18next.t`, but we want to stick with `this.props.t` which was used from the beginning. One reason that we want to use `this.props.t` is because it's the only one that works with `storybook`. Using the other two functions just shows the key in the stories.

Any suggestion for fixing the `i18next-scanner` config (or something else), to make the scanning of the code pick up uses of `this.props.t` is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

options: {
defaultLng: 'en',
debug: true,
func: {
list: ['t','this.props.t', 'i18next.t', 'i18n.t'],

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).